# No longer able to connect to MySQL through socket

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lamp

I was trying to do replication and setup my server as slave. i first changed permissions using

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

then

```
sudo chown user:user -R /etc/mysql
```

then i tried installing notepad and it crashed. restarted the server and installed Jedit. Finally I edited the my.cnf file added

```
server-id=1359126008
```

under `[mysqld]`

after a restart of mysql and then of the server i got this error

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

now I am not able to connect any longer. Also the `mysqld.sock` file does not exist in that folder.

**UPDATE**

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo service mysql stop
stop: Unknown instance: 
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo service mysql status
mysql stop/waiting
```

**UPDATE 2**

location from my.cnf: `log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log`

all existing lines in log:

```
130125 10:38:09 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130125 10:38:09 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 2 events
130125 10:38:09  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130125 10:38:11  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 7759014
130125 10:38:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

**UPDATE 3**
nothing related to mysql is running.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ps -A
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 init
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    3 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/0
    6 ?        00:00:00 migration/0
    7 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/0
    8 ?        00:00:00 migration/1
   10 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/1
   11 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/1
   12 ?        00:00:00 migration/2
   14 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/2
   15 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/2
   16 ?        00:00:00 migration/3
   18 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/3
   19 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/3
   20 ?        00:00:00 cpuset
   21 ?        00:00:00 khelper
   22 ?        00:00:00 kdevtmpfs
   23 ?        00:00:00 netns
   24 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u:1
   25 ?        00:00:00 sync_supers
   26 ?        00:00:00 bdi-default
   27 ?        00:00:00 kintegrityd
   28 ?        00:00:00 kblockd
   29 ?        00:00:00 ata_sff
   30 ?        00:00:00 khubd
   31 ?        00:00:00 md
   32 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:1
   35 ?        00:00:00 kworker/3:1
   36 ?        00:00:00 khungtaskd
   37 ?        00:00:00 kswapd0
   38 ?        00:00:00 ksmd
   39 ?        00:00:00 khugepaged
   40 ?        00:00:00 fsnotify_mark
   41 ?        00:00:00 ecryptfs-kthrea
   42 ?        00:00:00 crypto
   51 ?        00:00:00 kthrotld
   52 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_0
   53 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_1
   54 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u:2
   56 ?        00:00:00 binder
   75 ?        00:00:00 deferwq
   76 ?        00:00:00 charger_manager
   77 ?        00:00:00 devfreq_wq
  123 ?        00:00:01 kworker/3:2
  182 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_2
  227 ?        00:00:00 kdmflush
  229 ?        00:00:00 kdmflush
  249 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/dm-0-8
  250 ?        00:00:00 ext4-dio-unwrit
  259 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_3
  260 ?        00:00:00 usb-storage
  261 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_4
  262 ?        00:00:00 usb-storage
  277 ?        00:00:00 flush-252:0
  353 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-br
  355 ?        00:00:00 udevd
  453 ?        00:00:00 edac-poller
  487 ?        00:00:00 ttm_swap
  514 ?        00:00:00 kpsmoused
  535 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
  541 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
  550 ?        00:00:00 bluetoothd
  581 ?        00:00:00 krfcommd
  592 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
  600 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
  619 ?        00:00:00 cupsd
  696 ?        00:00:00 kvm-irqfd-clean
  699 ?        00:00:01 kworker/2:3
  701 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:3
  799 ?        00:00:00 upstart-socket-
  957 ?        00:00:00 dhclient
 1024 ?        00:00:00 winbindd
 1035 ?        00:00:00 modem-manager
 1040 ?        00:00:00 winbindd
 1047 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager
 1058 ?        00:00:00 polkitd
 1098 ?        00:00:00 udevd
 1099 ?        00:00:00 udevd
 1125 tty4     00:00:00 getty
 1133 tty5     00:00:00 getty
 1139 tty2     00:00:00 getty
 1140 tty3     00:00:00 getty
 1144 tty6     00:00:00 getty
 1158 ?        00:00:00 acpid
 1168 ?        00:00:00 atd
 1169 ?        00:00:00 cron
 1174 ?        00:00:00 lightdm
 1175 ?        00:00:00 whoopsie
 1177 ?        00:00:00 irqbalance
 1237 tty7     00:04:31 Xorg
 1437 tty1     00:00:00 getty
 1445 ?        00:00:00 accounts-daemon
 1463 ?        00:00:00 console-kit-dae
 1584 ?        00:00:00 upowerd
 1676 ?        00:00:00 lightdm
 1757 ?        00:00:00 colord
 1844 ?        00:00:00 rtkit-daemon
 1960 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-d
 1971 ?        00:00:00 gnome-session
 2006 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
 2009 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch
 2010 ?        00:00:01 dbus-daemon
 2012 ?        00:00:00 at-spi-bus-laun
 2016 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 2019 ?        00:00:00 at-spi2-registr
 2033 ?        00:00:01 gnome-settings-
 2038 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd
 2042 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-fuse
 2062 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
 2063 ?        00:00:00 gconf-helper
 2065 ?        00:00:00 gconfd-2
 2067 ?        00:00:00 dconf-service
 2068 ?        00:00:29 nautilus
 2072 ?        00:00:00 polkit-gnome-au
 2073 ?        00:00:00 bluetooth-apple
 2076 ?        00:00:00 nm-applet
 2078 ?        00:00:00 gnome-fallback-
 2090 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-udisks2-vo
 2094 ?        00:00:00 udisksd
 2109 ?        00:00:08 dropbox
 2115 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-afc-volume
 2122 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
 2133 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-trash
 2146 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-burn
 2163 ?        00:00:01 bamfdaemon
 2178 ?        00:00:00 notify-osd
 2206 ?        00:00:00 sh
 2207 ?        00:00:01 gtk-window-deco
 2218 ?        00:06:56 compiz
 2247 ?        00:00:09 unity-panel-ser
 2249 ?        00:00:06 hud-service
 2260 ?        00:00:00 indicator-sound
 2262 ?        00:00:00 indicator-sessi
 2268 ?        00:00:00 indicator-print
 2273 ?        00:00:00 indicator-datet
 2275 ?        00:00:00 indicator-appli
 2277 ?        00:00:00 indicator-messa
 2304 ?        00:00:00 evolution-sourc
 2313 ?        00:00:00 goa-daemon
 2317 ?        00:00:00 geoclue-master
 2330 ?        00:00:00 ubuntu-geoip-pr
 2335 ?        00:00:00 telepathy-indic
 2341 ?        00:00:00 mission-control
 2348 ?        00:00:00 signon-ui
 2351 ?        00:00:00 zeitgeist-datah
 2357 ?        00:00:00 zeitgeist-daemo
 2363 ?        00:00:00 zeitgeist-fts
 2371 ?        00:00:00 cat
 2375 ?        00:00:07 firefox
 2403 ?        00:00:00 unity-webapps-s
 2421 ?        00:00:00 unity-applicati
 2423 ?        00:00:00 unity-files-dae
 2425 ?        00:00:00 unity-gwibber-d
 2427 ?        00:00:00 unity-music-dae
 2429 ?        00:00:00 unity-lens-phot
 2431 ?        00:00:00 unity-shopping-
 2433 ?        00:00:00 unity-lens-vide
 2514 ?        00:00:00 unity-musicstor
 2515 ?        00:00:00 unity-scope-gdo
 2543 ?        00:00:00 unity-scope-vid
 2573 ?        00:00:00 teamviewer
 2578 ?        00:00:00 wrapper
 2604 ?        00:00:38 TeamViewer.exe
 2607 ?        00:00:47 wineserver
 2611 ?        00:00:00 services.exe
 2632 ?        00:00:00 update-notifier
 2643 ?        00:00:00 system-service-
 2654 ?        00:06:38 TeamViewer_Desk
 2679 ?        00:00:00 deja-dup-monito
 2700 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-metadata
 2825 ?        00:00:03 gnome-terminal
 2834 ?        00:00:00 gnome-pty-helpe
 2835 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 3629 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 3636 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 3637 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 3638 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 3639 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 3640 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 3641 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 3644 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 3645 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 3646 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 3647 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 4089 ?        00:00:00 kworker/2:0
 4419 ?        00:00:08 java
 4465 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:0
 4486 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:2
 4552 ?        00:00:00 kworker/2:1
 4762 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

**UPDATE 4**

I couldn't get it working. Re-installed mysql and now its working. If you are worried about the databases, mysql gave me the option of removing them or keeping them. I kept them, installed mysql, used the same root pass as before and now everything is working!! thanks guys!

Comment: Is the `mysqld` process running?

Comment: Look for the error log file. Inside `my.cnf`, you should see `log-error`. If that variable does not exist, look in the data folder for a file with the file extension `.err`. When you find it, please post the last 20 lines.

Comment: Your `ps` listing will show `mysqld` if present.

Comment: id also like to mention that I did do a sudo apt-get update. this may have caused something?

Comment: Why did you make my.cnf 777?

Answer (score 2):

What worries me is the

```
sudo chown user:user -R /etc/mysql
```

I do not trust any other user but the `mysql` user to handle the MySQL Instance

Since mysql is down, do the following:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /etc/mysql
service mysql start
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: darn! that actually sounds like a good idea! well I couldn't take it so I reinstalled mysql lol. But if in the future i need to edit the my.cnf file how can i do that without changing permissions?

Comment: You could perhaps just `sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: ah, perfect!! thats what I need to start doing. this stuff is very sensitive. this is my third time messing something up. nothing like windows.